# Importing json file fails, reporting "unsupported protocol blob" and Axioserror

Tags: reactjs, axios

while uploading json file, facing error like unsupported blog type and axioserror

[image]

axiosservice.js file looks like below

```
class AxiosService {

    instance = axios.create({

        paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { encode: true })


    });
    
    requestInterceptor = this.instance.interceptors.request.use(

        (config) => {
            let accessToken = localStorage.getItem(SESSION_CONSTANTS.ACCESS_TOKEN);

            config.headers[HTTP_HEADERS.AUTHORIZATION] = `bearer ${accessToken}`;

            config.headers[HTTP_HEADERS.X_AUTH_TOKEN] = `${accessToken}`

            return config;
        },
        (err) => Promise.reject(err)
    );
    // Add a 401 response interceptor

    responseInterceptor = this.instance.interceptors.response.use(

        (response) => response,

        (error) => {

            if (error.response && error.response.status === HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {

                // logging out the user in case of 401 response

                LogoutChannel.broadcastMessage(SESSION_CONSTANTS.LOGOUT_BROADCAST_MSG);

                Store.dispatch(actions.logout(false));
            }
            if (

                this.isHandleMethodNotAllowedError(error.config.url) &&

                error.response &&

                error.response.status === HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

            ) {
                // Handle the error in case of 405 response

                Store.dispatch(actions.handleErrorMessage(true, error.response.data));

                return Promise.reject({});

            }
            return Promise.reject(error);

        }
    );
```

jsonimporter.js file looks like below

```
    onUploadButtonClick = () => {

        this.setState({ submitLoading: true });

        let jsonContent = {};

        axios({

            method: 'get',

            url: this.props.existingFileData[0].file.preview,

            responseType: 'blob'

        }).then((response) => {

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsText(response.data);

            reader.onloadend = () => {

                jsonContent = reader.result;

                if (this.isValidJSON(jsonContent)) {

                    this.callNBI(JSON.parse(jsonContent));

                } else {

                    this.callNBI(jsonContent);

                }
            };
        });
    };
```